# Error when trying to modify URL path in R API package

Tags: r, httr

I am writing my first R API package and am following Hadley Wickham's Best Practices Guide for API Packages and have hit a snag. The base URL for the API is https://journaltransfer.issn.org/api?query=. The problem I am facing is that when I attempt to modify the url, the query isn't appended to the end after the = sign, but instead replaces the word api. How do I fix this issue?

```
library(httr)

rtransfers <- function(path) {
  url <- modify_url("https://journaltransfer.issn.org/api?query=", path = path)
  GET(url)
}

resp <- rtransfers("*")
```

I expect the url that would have been run by `rtransfers` to be: https://journaltransfer.issn.org/api?query=* but instead it ends up being https://journaltransfer.issn.org/*?query=

Comment: Try this? `modify_url("https://journaltransfer.issn.org/api?", query = path)`

Comment: That worked in terms of fixing the above issue of having api inadvertently replaced, but the output now comes out as [link] (https://journaltransfer.issn.org/api?*) when I need it to be query=*

Comment: Probably not the best way and hopefully someone comes up with a canonical `httr` solution but maybe: `paste0("https://journaltransfer.issn.org/api?query=", path)`? and do away with `modify_url`? I do note that it takes forever to access for me.

Comment: This seems to have worked. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`modify_url("https://journaltransfer.issn.org/api?query=", query = list(query = path))`